# Are these series of requests being executed in parallel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, request

I am using redux to dispatch a series of requests. My intention is to write the actions logic so that **the series will be executed in parallel** (the volume of requested data is not huge, but considerable).

However, looking at redux devtools inspector pane, it does seem like the request are executed as a perfect queue – first come, first served:

[image]

Which raises suspicion That these request are, in reality, serial.

I've tested this only in local enviroment, however the results are the same even if throttling via devtools to "slow 3"G.

Here's related redux code:

```
const yearsSince2013 = Array.from(
  { length: new Date().getFullYear() - 2013 + 1 },
  (_, i) => i + 2013,
)
   
export const fetchProjectsOfOneYear = year => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch(fetchProjectsOfOneYearInit(year))
    const response = await client.get(`projects/${year}`)
    dispatch(fetchProjectsOfOneYearSuccess(response.data, year))
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(fetchProjectsOfOneYearFailure(year, error))
  }
}

export const fetchAllProjects = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch(fetchAllProjectsInit())
    // Is the line below resulting in parallel or serial execution?
    Promise.all(yearsSince2013.map(async year => dispatch(fetchProjectsOfOneYear(year)))).then(_ =>
      dispatch(fetchAllProjectsSuccess()),
    )
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(fetchAllProjectsFailure(error))
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, they are in parallel when you use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), you can see all the fetches starting logs and then all the resolves. It is coincidence they all resolve in the same order they started.

Comment: @HMR Thanks for your insight. I thought it would probably be the case, but I wasn't sure. I've never used `async map` before.